# Replace imports but keep string

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like to know if there is any way to make the following change to all files at once

```
import component from 'Components/Path/compoent.ts'
```

to

```
const component = () => import('Components/Path/compoent.ts')
```

Comment: You can do a global find and replace via `Ctrl+Shift+h`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want to replace everything with this syntax, then a [regex is your friend here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_search-across-files):

```
import (\S+) from '([^']+)'
```

Replace with:

```
const $1 = () => import('$2')
```

To just replace the constant string:

```
import component from '([^']+)'
```

Replace with:

```
const component = () => import('$1')
```

Comment: how can I add to Regex just the string that starts with 'Component'? ty

Comment: Replace the expression parts with a constant instead.